# value not getting assigned to variable in vbscript

Tags: vbscript

```
if ( IsPEnabled = "TRUE" AND IsPChecked = 1) Then
    canRemove = "true"
elseif (IsPEnabled = "FALSE" AND IsPChecked = 0) Then
    canRemove = "true"
else 
    canRemove = "false"
End If
```

I can't seem to find any errors in the above piece of code, but whenever canRemove always remains false even if both if and else if conditions are satisfied. Note: All variables are declared and have correct values.

Comment: Add `Debug.Print` for `IsPEnabled`, `IsPChecked` before the first `if`, and `Debug.Print("1")` (and "2" and "3") within each option within the `if`.

Comment: @FDavidov silliest thing i've ever done, the values were being set as "True" and I was checking for "TRUE"

Comment: Well Sir, you have just joined a very crowded club (I'm also a member of course)!!! I guess you found it with the prints, right?

Comment: Yeah. Thanks,still cannot believe I wasted time for this :)

Comment: Don't feel bad. It happens to everyone. Last, if you don't mind, could you up-vote my comment? Thanks!!!

Comment: By the way, to prevent this type of issues, I always convert to uppercase and compare (except in cases that case is important of course).

Comment: @FDavidov they couldn't have found it with `Debug.Print` unless they were using VBA, the question is tagged VBScript which doesn't include the  `Debug.Print`.

Comment: Why are you using strings to represent and compare booleans why not use actual `True` and `False`?

Comment: @Lankymart, it would be fair to assume that he would be capable of searching for the correct command (i.e. `Wscript.Echo "blabla"`). The main purpose of my comment was to **do something to check the _entry conditions_ of this piece of code**. With that assumption in mind, I select to assume that my suggestion was helpful, even a little. Eventually, it is for him to say if it helped or not, wouldn't you agree?

Comment: @FDavidov No, I personally think without knowing the OPs level of aptitude writing `Debug.Print` is just asking for trouble *(not to mention, you highlighted it as `code`)*. Actually, stating what you did in bold is far more helpful and less open to interpretation. It's also not just about helping the OP but also others who coming looking at this question.

Comment: @Lankymart, since today I feel very positive, I'm willing to accept your correction specially for the second part (others reading this post).

Comment: @FDavidov glad to hear. Btw I wasn't saying your comment was unhelpful just unclear.

Answer (score 1):

Just to expand on this a little more, it's good practice when checking strings to force them to be either upper or lower case so that you can be certain that they match properly.

Obviously if you require to check that a string matches a specific case sensitive format, this is not an appropriate approach!

You could use:

```
If (UCase(IsPEnabled) = "TRUE" AND IsPChecked = 1) Then
    canRemove = "true"
ElseIf (UCase(IsPEnabled) = "FALSE" AND IsPChecked = 0) Then
    canRemove = "true"
Else 
    canRemove = "false"
End If
```

This way you force the change on the `IsPEnabled` variable purely for the comparison and don't actually change its value.  Should you want to use lower case instead, you would use the following code:

```
If (LCase(IsPEnabled) = "true" AND IsPChecked = 1) Then
    canRemove = "true"
ElseIf (LCase(IsPEnabled) = "false" AND IsPChecked = 0) Then
    canRemove = "true"
Else 
    canRemove = "false"
End If
```

In general, it is also better form not to use `strings` for `True` and `False` values.  If you had these as `Boolean` types instead, you wouldn't need the string comparison at all:

```
If (IsPEnabled AND IsPChecked = 1) Then
    canRemove = True
ElseIf (Not IsPEnabled AND IsPChecked = 0) Then
    canRemove = True
Else 
    canRemove = False
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried this in console looking at Upper case vs lower case

this worked

```
if ( IsPEnabled = "true" AND IsPChecked = 1) Then
    canRemove = "true"
elseif (IsPEnabled = "false" AND IsPChecked = 0) Then
    canRemove = "true"
else 
    canRemove = "false"
End If
```